# How to activate a child of a parent object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I have a parent object that is not meant to be activated until later in the game. So I want to only activate when it enters a trigger.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SetActiveOnTriggerEnter : MonoBehaviour {

    //public string FindGameOBJ; <-To be implemented for future re-usability. Ignore it for now.
   // public string ComponentToActivate; <-To be implemented for future re-usability. Ignore it for now.

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider coll) // Collision detection.
    {
        if (coll.tag == "Ball") //Checks the tag to see if it is the PARENT OBJECT.
        {
                if (GameObject.Find("BallHealZone") == null) //Looks for the CHILD OBJECT, and if it is null than move forward.
                {
                    Debug.Log("Activating BallHealZone! :)"); //Tells me if it found said object, and confirms it is indeed null (yes it works).
                    gameObject.SetActive(true); //Activates the CHILD OF PARENT OBJECT.
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Basically as you can see it checks if the tag is correct finds the GameObject (the child is one that is supposed to be activated), logs it, and is supposed to set it active. The log says the conditions are met, but it doesn't fire off the gameObject.SetActive(true); command.

How do I activate a child of a parent object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you cannot find a deactivated game object with GameObject.Find() method. Because GameObject.Find() finds and return "gameObject" but there is no game object with this name in your scene. You should find transform of this game object. So if you want to activate the child object, try this one.

( I suppose that this script attached to parent object)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SetActiveOnTriggerEnter : MonoBehaviour {

    //public string FindGameOBJ; <-To be implemented for future re-usability. Ignore it for now.
    // public string ComponentToActivate; <-To be implemented for future re-usability. Ignore it for now.

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider coll) // Collision detection.
    {
        if (coll.tag == "Ball") //Checks the tag to see if it is the PARENT OBJECT.
        {
                if (!transform.FindChild("BallHealZone").gameObject.activeInHierarchy) //This is better form for looking , but there is a one better way, GetChild. You can see it on below. 
                {
                    Debug.Log("Activating BallHealZone! :)"); //Tells me if it found said object, and confirms it is indeed null (yes it works).
                    transform.FindChild("BallHealZone").gameObject.SetActive(true); //Activates the CHILD OF PARENT OBJECT.
                    //or if you know index of child in parent you can use GetChild method for a faster one
                    transform.GetChild(indexOfChild).gameObject.SetActive(true); // this also activates child, but this is faster than FindChild method
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it `GameObject.Find("BallHealZone")` returns the reference to `gameObject` if gameObject was `null` that means the reference for this object has not been created yet. Typically that means that you to instantiate the object before you you execute the method unless its a static method.

Try inserting `gameObject = new WHATEVEROBJECTTHISIS();`

If this isnt the case could you expand the code snippet with some more details. What bothers me is that you should get an exception if the object is null. I have no idea why this happening in that case.

Comment: It's not trying to instantiate anything... The code waits for something with the proper tag to enter, looks for the game object, and checks if it's null. If it is null (which it is) it returns with a debug.log (which is working), and is supposed to activate the child object (which it is not doing).

Comment: I've updated my question's code snippet with comments to better explain what is (or should be) happening.